# When using ScrollViewer as part of template for some control, the left click is handled

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, scrollviewer

Consider first version of code (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <local:CustomControl1 Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="Red"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

where CustomControl1 derived from ItemsControl. Inside CustomControl1 , I overriding OnMouseDown event. This code works perfectly, and i do catch mouse down event.

Now second version of code (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<local:CustomControl1 Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="Red"/>
```

Inside Generic.xaml, I changing template of my items control:

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <ScrollViewer 
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                        >
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

When I putting scrollviewer as part of control template, I DO NOT receiving OnMouseDownEvent anymore (for left click). For some reason, now the mouse down event marked as handled. If instead of overriding OnMouseDown I using the following statement inside items control constructor, the event is catched:

```
AddHandler(Mouse.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseDown), true);
```

First, I would like to understand why placing scrollviewer inside template changing behavior of mouse down. Second, does anyone know some workaround? 
The solution I proposed (by catching handled events) is not acceptable for me. In my application, I need to handle mouse down events only if none of items control children handled it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at the default `Template` for a `ListBox` for example (which also derives from `ItemsControl`), you'll see that the `ScrollViewer` has `Focusable="False"` set in the Template. This allows the mouse events to pass through to your control

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Focusable="False" >
    <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I don't understand.  how exactly does focusable = false affect event handling?

Answer (score 0):

As regards the event being handled, a root cause is that when a `ScrollViewer` is focusable, its internal `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method will try to get focus and if it succeeds, *it handles the event*.

Here's the very code from the VS2019 decompilation:

```
public class ScrollViewer : ContentControl
{

    ...

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Focus())
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    ...

}
```

So one method is to set `Focusable="False"` (as noted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056857/3195477)) because it prevents this from occurring. But that might be too extreme or restrictive (it was for me).  For example, I found that preventing my `ScrollViewer` from receiving focus would [stop keybindings from being initiated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432365/3195477). But if it had focus, they would work.

So another more flexible approach is to add an event handler like so:

```
<ScrollViewer
     MouseLeftButtonDown="handler"
     />
```

Where `handler` just does:

```
void handler(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

Or if you happen to be creating your own derived ScrollViewer you can just override `OnMouseLeftButtonDown`.