# ListView InputBinding MouseBinding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why does not `ListView.InputBindings` work?

I've implemented `Interaction.Triggers` the same way and it works just fine.

```
<ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemSelectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView1,Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <ListView.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ItemSelectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView1,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </ListView.InputBindings>
</ListView>
```

Really don't want to use that extra assmebly if it should work without (`System.Windows.Interactivity` for `Interaction.Triggers`)

Comment: Is it possible to use the InputBindings on the ListViewItem, rather than the ListView? Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

As @Grx70 mentions in the comment to this answer, the `LeftClick` mouse gesture defined in the parent `ListView` won't work for a `ListViewItem` because that item handles this gesture to gain focus, so it doesn't bubble that gesture up.

You could shift your `InputBinding` processing to the `ListViewItem` itself:

```
<ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding A}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelectCommand, ElementName=listView1}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView1,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You could also read more about how `InputBinding`s work in [this qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316274/inputbindings-work-only-when-focused), there is an answer explaining that. The answer suggests to create an attached behavior also.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true that command bindings work only for focused controls. Apparently handling starts with the focused control, but according to [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941707/keybinding-in-usercontrol-doesnt-work-when-textbox-has-the-focus) gestures also bubble up. On the other hand they seem to stop as soon as they're handled (which would be consistent with event bubbling), and I presume `MouseClick` gesture is handled by all focusable controls  to gain focus - thus preventing it from bubbling up.

Comment: I'm not sure how this will work with defined columns inside a GridView (using the ListView.View attribute)