# Control keys not working while window is disable and again Enable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a XAML MainWindow and Child User control loaded on that window. On button click event in user control I disable mainWindow as Well as User Control till a work on button click is not finished. When I again updating the property from User control to enable the window again, now user control keys are not working, because while debugging its showing IsEnabled Property of window/user control is still disable. I am also forcefully updating user control property **this.IsEnabled = true;** but still its not updating IsEnabled property of class true.
How could I update the mainwindow and user control property to enable or how could my Control keys can work again.

Comment: Try to [set focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23316274/1997232) after enabling it.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks for reply, but focus is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set mainWindow.IsEnabled to false, you cannot set userControl.IsEnabled to true.  You have to set the mainWindow.IsEnabled to true first.  You cannot have an enabled control inside a disabled control.

I wrote a simple WPF app with a user control with a button.  The main window has the user control and the code for the user control is:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    DispatcherTimer m_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        m_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.IsEnabled = true;
        m_timer.Stop();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.IsEnabled = false;
        m_timer.Start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its main window is enabled already but i don't know why user control is not enabling.

Comment: You will have to post some code.  Also try Snoop (https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) and try manually inspecting and setting IsEnabled in it in the visual tree.